# What is the keyPassword I am supposed to use for signing a React Native project?

Tags: react-native, keytool, app-signing

I have made an app project in React Native, and I want to build its apk. I am following the official documentation as shown here https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.

It says that I must first generate a private signing key using `keytool`. I have followed the instructions for windows. Here is the terminal output:

```
PS C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin> keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password:
What is your first and last name?
  [Unknown]:  My Name
What is the name of your organizational unit?
  [Unknown]:  Myself
What is the name of your organization?
  [Unknown]:  OrgName
What is the name of your City or Locality?
  [Unknown]:  CityName
What is the name of your State or Province?
  [Unknown]:  StateName
What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
  [Unknown]:  XY
Is CN=My Name, OU=Myself, O=OrgName, L=CityName, ST=StateName, C=XY correct?
  [no]:  yes

Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate (SHA256withRSA) with a validity of 10,000 days
        for: CN=My Name, OU=Myself, O=OrgName, L=CityName, ST=StateName, C=XY
[Storing my-upload-key.keystore]
PS C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_271\bin>
```

Immediately after this, the documentation says I must enter the generated keystore password and key password into this file

> 1. Place the `my-upload-key.keystore` file under the `android/app` directory in your project folder.
> 2. Edit the file `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` or `android/gradle.properties`, and add the following (replace `*****` with the correct keystore password, alias and key password),
>
> ```
> MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE=my-upload-key.keystore
> MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS=my-key-alias
> MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
> MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
> ```

Later, in `android/app/build.gradle`, I am to add this:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {            
            storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
```

I believe the "storePassword" is the "keystore password" which I created earlier when i was prompted by keytool, but I do not remember ever seeing or generating a "keyPassword".

Perhaps this is a banal question, but how do I find my "keyPassword"? Even other tutorial websites seem to assume the user already has it or knows it. Is the "keyPassword" something that I must create right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android Studio go **Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / Apk**.
You will see button Create New on second step.
There you will be able to create key with password

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this an alternative method than using the React Native CLI? Or is this something that should be done AFTER doing the steps I was talking about?

Comment: yes, this an alternative method and easiest, you can also provide password via console command adding -keypass MYPASS  before -keystore my-upload-key.keystore

Comment: when i want to create a newer version of the app, should I still use "Generate signed bundle"?

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the key using command line:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then you need to add the key inside android/app folder and add the keystore name inside android/app/build.gradle file, in the signingConfigs configuration.

Comment: In signingConfigs: 

`
signingConfigs {
        release {            
                storeFile file(...)
                storePassword ...
                keyAlias ...
                keyPassword ...
            
        }
    }
`


I do not understand what I should put for "keyPassword".


The command line you have given is a bit different from the one given in the documentation. Does yours explicitly generate, or ask for a keyPassword?

Comment: The keystore password is generated in the command. The parameter is -storepass and the password in this case is "android". You can change it for whatever you want.